# Does currently running thread hold the lock while sleeping?

Tags: java, multithreading

As documentation says

> while sleeping a Thread does not release the locks it holds

However my code snippet demonstrates **it does release** the lock

```
public class SynchronizationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Common c = new Common();
        new PersonONE(c);
        new PersonTWO(c);
    }
}

class Common {
    private String message = "This is shared message";
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

class PersonONE extends Thread {
    private Common c;
    public PersonONE(Common c) {
        this.c = c;
        start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (c.getClass()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("PersonONE: " + c.getMessage());
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}

class PersonTWO extends Thread {
    private Common c;
    public PersonTWO(Common c) {
        this.c = c;
        start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("PersonTWO: "+c.getMessage());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

PersonONE: This is shared message
PersonTWO: This is shared message
PersonONE: This is shared message
PersonTWO: This is shared message
PersonONE: This is shared message
PersonTWO: This is shared message
PersonONE: This is shared message
PersonTWO: This is shared message
PersonONE: This is shared message
PersonTWO: This is shared message

So, the question is: where am I wrong ?

Comment: You don't explain how you reached the conclusion you reached from the evidence you presented.

Comment: If I may, try to implement Runnable instead of extending Thread. It's a better practice

Comment: @JFPicard: there are multiple best practices getting violated in the posted code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PersonTWO doesn't try to acquire the lock.

See below for an example that does demonstrate that sleeping does not release a lock.

```
private static class Locker implements Runnable {
    private final Object lock;
    private final String message;

    private Locker(final Object lock, final String message) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int numThreads = 2;
    final Object lock = new Object();
    for (int i=0;i<numThreads;i++) {
        new Thread(new Locker(lock, "Hello - " + i)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put another way, the two threads are not acquiring the same lock they can run concurrently. +1

Comment: @brain, if `PersonONE` doesn't sleep inside synchronized block `PersonTWO` cannot get access to common object even when he doesn't try to acquire lock.

Comment: @Anarantt That's the way people usually do it, but that's not what your code does. A lock doesn't know what it locks, it's your job as the programmer to make the lock protect something in a useful way.

Comment: @Anarantt: if your first thread doesn’t sleep, it simply completes before the second even starts. This does not mean that the second gets no access, it simply doesn’t even try while the first is running. You need a much longer loop to demonstrate concurrency then…